# I have a OS Error when I did my Django when I followed the tutorial

Tags: python, django

I followed the tutorial at [Django for Beginners](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/18/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-3.html#testing-the-form-view) (I am at part 3 right now). I am having trouble fixing an OS Error when I ran the site at 127.0.0.1:8000.  I got a ModuleNotFoundError, and I feel that the trouble is in my settings.py. I typed in python manage.py runserver when my virtual environment was active.

The errors I got were the following:
OSError: [WinError] 123 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named widget-tweaks.

Here's my settings.py file.  This is where I added django-widget tweaks.

```
Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '(6@pj06#0x%r)xyw3#!79hys%aba*)b8-6+c=jncuk5+5ei#(i'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'widget-tweaks',

    'boards',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

In new_topic.py, Here is where I uploaded the Django-widget tweaks.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load widget_tweaks %} -> loaded it here.

{% block title %}Start a New Topic{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Boards</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'board_topics' board.pk %}">{{ board.name }}</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">New topic</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}

        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}

        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small class="form-text text-muted">
            {{ field.help_text }}
          </small>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

My end goal is to get a rendered form, but the ModuleNotFoundError is not letting me render the form or run the webpage. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling widget-tweaks using the pip install django-widget-tweaks and it's still giving me an error and a hard time.

Can someone show me how to fix this? I never received this error when I ran it the first time.

Comment: in `INSTALLED_APPS`, try replacing `widget-tweaks` with `widget_tweaks`

Comment: I replaced widget-tweaks with widget_tweaks.  The error was simply a case of mistyping. Thanks yedpotrzitko!!!

Comment: alright, I'll add it as an answer, so this question can be marked as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [installation instructions](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks#installation), the value in `INSTALLED_APPS` should be `widget_tweaks` instead of `widget-tweaks`.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace widget-tweaks with widget_tweaks in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: That helps in solving it.